# Sites sector plots on Google Earth using Python appearing elliptical instead of circular

Tags: python

I am using below function to create sectors of sites for a telecom operator. I am using lines to show different technologies deployed to keep visuals simple. Problem I am having is that sector appears slightly skewed towards elliptical side. Showing as in pictures.

I am feeding out put of this function into SimpleKML which creates KML for my purpose. If any one can guide me to make them proper circular rather than elliptical it will be great.

I have seen a similar question about some one had similar problem while creating a buffer circle around a point in GE. In one of the answers some one resolved it by using PROJ library. From that solution I can't understand how to solve my problem.

```
def get_points(lon, lat,ht, sectRadius_km, azimuth, shapeType,offsetAzimuth_deg):
earthCircumference_km=40007.863 #40075
sectorRadius_deg = 360*(sectRadius_km/earthCircumference_km)
if shapeType == "Point":
    sectorPointLon_deg = lon + sectorRadius_deg * math.sin((azimuth+offsetAzimuth_deg)*math.pi/180)        
    sectorPointLat_deg = lat + sectorRadius_deg * math.cos((azimuth+offsetAzimuth_deg)*math.pi/180)
    #print([sectorPointLon_deg , sectorPointLat_deg])        
    return [(sectorPointLon_deg , sectorPointLat_deg, ht)]
elif shapeType == "Line":
    sectorPointLon_deg = lon + sectorRadius_deg * math.sin((azimuth+offsetAzimuth_deg)*math.pi/180)        
    sectorPointLat_deg = lat + sectorRadius_deg * math.cos((azimuth+offsetAzimuth_deg)*math.pi/180)
    #print([sectorPointLon_deg , sectorPointLat_deg])        
    return [(lon, lat,ht),(sectorPointLon_deg , sectorPointLat_deg,ht)]
```

[image: Picture Showing Elliptical Skewness]

[image: This is how sites orientation looks like]

Comment: Circular plots *should* look elliptical in Web Mercator.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339219/why-does-size-of-circle-object-drawn-in-google-maps-increase-when-moving-it-away

Comment: Is there a way to correct this mathematically? There must be someway...

Comment: You want to correct truth with math?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/creating-buffer-circle-x-kilometers-from-point-using-python

Comment: I am not able to apply this at sector level thats where I want help.

Comment: You're asking for us to help you misrepresent an object with equidistant segments as circular in Web Mercator, when the inherent distortion of the projection should render the object as ellipsoid. We had a *"How to lie with maps"* project in my Cartography class, but it focused more on statistics and symbolization than actual lying (and was actually an ethics lesson). I will not be a party to this effort.

Comment: Totally beyond belief.... All I am interested in is to display my sites sector-azimuth properly. Don't know how you comprehend this is as a misrepresentation. Sector direction appears skewed due to elliptical appearance. Thanks for your time.

Comment: People landing on this page might have a look at this answser: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443782/136555